# Remove Redundant text when displaying titles within a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a loop that calls all my post titles of a CPT, each of with starts the the same X characters.

**Example:**

XX XXX Alabama

XX XXX Alaska

etc

**How can I remove the 'XXXXX' so all that is displayed is:**

Alabama

Alaska

etc

**Here's my loop:**

```
<?php
wp_reset_postdata();
$state_list = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'play_states',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,

));

while ($state_list->have_posts()) : $state_list->the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="' . $class . '">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I added the following:

```
$title = get_the_title();
$newTitle = str_replace("XXXXX Post", "", $title);
```

After the line opening the while statement. By simply replaceing "XXXXX Post" with the text I wanted to remove I was able to accomplish my goal.

Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Find position of a first space and get a substring starting from this position.

Comment: @u_mulder the 15th character would start the actual state listings. I'm not sure how to write a substring. Looking it up now in the codex

Comment: There's a `substr` function in a core php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` function! Here we go!

```
$variable = str_replace("XXXXX","", $variable);
```

Let me know it that helps!

**In A Loop!**

```
// I hope you have Array named $cities Containing the cities!
foreach($cities as $city)
{
    $city_final = str_replace("XXXX","",$city);
    // Do whatever you want with $city_final now!
}
```

Sorry if there ar syntax Errors here! I am trying to give you the idea! I don't think there are syntax Errors too!

Comment: How does this fit within the loop?

Comment: I cannot figure out how to get it get it to work. I'm in a rush right now so will have to check later. I'm using while, not foreach though

Comment: No worries man! It will work! Logic is what you need to understand! You can code accordingly in WP!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141495/discussion-between-adarsh-sojitra-and-mdnash).

Answer (score 0):

This will split your text into 2 parts on a space.  You want the second element in the array.

```
$onlyState=explode(' ', $stateWithJunk, 2); 
// do something with $onlyState[1]
```

Comment: And with `North Carolina` for example?

Comment: There are actually multiple spaces. XXX XXXX [STATE]

Comment: He asked to get rid of the first part of the string.  So, if we had 'XXXXXX North Carolina' and he used this method he would get $onlyState[1]='North Carolina'  The 2 in the code makes sure it only splits into 2 parts on the first white space.

Comment: @mdash You should change your written explanation to show that.